why indirect variable reference not work in bash dictionary
I know it( ! indirect variable reference ${!parameter}) will work in the general variable, but I need to use it in dictionary, and it doesn't work. Could somebody know the reason and how to achieve it?
I only konw the dictionary name and the key name, how to get the value in the dictionary?
#!/bin/bash
declare -A a_dict
a_dict=(
    ['aa']='valueA'
    ['ab']='valueB'
)

declare -A b_dict
b_dict=(
    ['ba']='valueA'
    ['bb']='valueB'
)

indirect_var(){
    name=$1
    key=$2
    echo ${!name[$key]}
}

indirect_var a_dict aa


Try indirect_var(){ v="$1[$2]"; echo "${!v}"; }

Both indexed and associative arrays essentially behave like ordinary parameters with fancy names. a_dict[aa] is more like a name than an operation.

I'm assuming the desired output for indirect_var a_dict aa is valueA; consider updating the question to explicitly state the desired output a) if my assumption is wrong and b) to lessen any potential confusion

fwiw, in OP's code - ${!name[$key]} - the ! is used to reference the indices of the array named name; if we start with name=(a b c) then echo "${!name[@]}" will generate 0 1 2; the point being that bash doesn't treat ${!name[...]} as an indirect reference but rather as a reference to the indices of array name[]; as @pmf has pointed out with their suggested code change, you need to get a bit more creative when combining indirect references and arrays

@pmf that's not safe if the key comes from an untrusted source. Try declare -A a; indirect_var a '$(uname >&2)' and you'll see.

@pmf That's also vulnerable: declare -A a; indirect_var 'a[$(uname >&2)\' ''.

@oguz Then check the name using declare -p and escape the key using @Q: indirect_var(){ v="$1[${2@Q}]"; declare -p -- "$1" >/dev/null && echo "${!v}"; }

@pmf Now it's longer and uglier than the accepted answer. What's the point?

In comments pmf has already provided a working function using an indirect reference.
If running bash 4.3+ another option would be a nameref, eg:
get_val() {
    local -n _var="$1"          # -n == nameref
    echo "${_var[$2]}"
}

### or as a one-liner:

get_val() { local -n _var="$1"; echo "${_var[$2]}"; }

Taking for a test drive:
$ get_val a_dict aa
valueA

$ get_val b_dict bb
valueB

$ get_val b_dict xyz
                          # blank output

$ get_val c_dict xyz
                          # blank output

